# Why is `to_numpy()` recognized as an attribute rather than a method of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, methods, attributes, numpy-ndarray

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class CLF:
    Weights = 0
    
    def fit(DF_input, DF_output, eta=0.1, drop=1000):
        X, y = DF_input.to_numpy(copy=True), DF_output.to_numpy(copy=True)
        N,d = X.shape
        m = len(np.unique(y))   
        self.Weights = np.random.normal(0,1, size=(d,m))


INPUT = pd.read_csv(path_input)
OUTPUT = pd.read_csv(path_output)
clf = CLF()
clf.fit(INPUT, OUTPUT)
```

I defined a method `.fit()` for the class I wrote. The first step is convert two dataframes into numpy arrays. However, I got the following error when I tried to use the method, although `INPUT.to_numpy(copy=True)` and `OUTPUT.to_numpy(copy=True)` both work fine in their own right. Can somebody help me out here? Why was `to_numpy` recognized as an **attribute** rather than a **method of dataframes**?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a3d455104534> in <module>
      1 clf = CLF()
----> 2 clf.fit(INPUT, OUTPUT)

<ipython-input-16-57babd738b2d> in fit(DF_input, DF_output, eta, drop)
      4 
      5     def fit(DF_input, DF_output, eta=0.1,drop=1000):
----> 6         X, y = DF_input.to_numpy(copy=True), DF_output.to_numpy(copy=True)
      7         N,d = X.shape
      8         m = len(np.unique(y))   # number of classes

AttributeError: 'CLF' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
```

Comment: Shouldn't your class method `fit` of `CLF` receive `self` as it's first argument? I think python expect's a class method to receive a self, and, thus, `CLF` thinks `DF_input` it it's self, and CLF does not have a method / attribute called `to_numpy` (because it's a DataFrame method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the first input for object method is usually reserved for `self`. The correct syntax should be:

```
class CLF:
    Weights = 0
    
    # notice the `self`
    def fit(self, DF_input, DF_output, eta=0.1, drop=1000):
        X, y = DF_input.to_numpy(copy=True), DF_output.to_numpy(copy=True)
        N,d = X.shape
        m = len(np.unique(y))   
        self.Weights = np.random.normal(0,1, size=(d,m))


INPUT = pd.read_csv(path_input)
OUTPUT = pd.read_csv(path_output)
clf = CLF()
clf.fit(INPUT, OUTPUT)
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An instance method is a type of attribute; this is a more general error message that keys on the `.` (dot) operator, rather than parsing through to the left parenthesis to discriminate your usage.

The problem is that you defined an instance method `fit`, but named your instance as `DF_input`.  I think you simply forgot the usual `self` naming for the implicit instance parameter.